# Pandas function that iterates over values in a series with case statements

Tags: function, pandas, case, series

I have a dataframe that has contains a column of integers. I want to write a function that takes a series as an argument, iterates through each value of the series, and performs a case statement on each integer within the series, and returns a new series from the results of the case statement. Currently I'm working with the following code and getting errors:

```
def function(series):
    if series['column_of_ints'] >= 0 and series['column_of_ints'] < 100:
        return series['column_of_ints']
    elif series['column_of_ints'] >= 100 and series['column_of_ints'] < 200:
        return series['column_of_ints'] + 1   
    else:
        return series['column_of_ints'] + 2

df['column_of_ints_v2'] = df['column_of_ints'].apply(function, axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the error log? I guess you have to replace `series['column_of_ints']` with `series` only in the `function(series)`, you're passing a series to the function not a dataframe.

Comment: the error is invalid index to scalar variable - possibly addressed by EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apply` you can achieve the same result much faster using 3 `.loc` calls:

```
df.loc[(df['column_of_ints'] >= 0) & (df['column_of_ints'] < 100), 'column_of_ints_v2'] df['column_of_ints']

df.loc[(df['column_of_ints'] >= 100) & (df['column_of_ints'] < 200), 'column_of_ints_v2'] = df['column_of_ints'] + 1   

df.loc[(df['column_of_ints'] < 0) & (df['column_of_ints'] >= 200), 'column_of_ints_v2'] = df['column_of_ints'] + 2
```

Or using `where`:

```
df['column_of_ints_v2'] = np.where((df['column_of_ints'] >= 0) & (df['column_of_ints') < 100), df['column_of_ints'] + 1, np.where( (df['column_of_ints'] >= 100) & (df['column_of_ints'] < 200), df['column_of_ints'] + 2, df['column_of_ints'] ))
```

As to why your code fails:

```
df['column_of_ints'].apply(function, axis=1)
```

df['column_of_ints'] is a Series not a DataFrame, there is no `axis=1` for `apply` method for a Series, you can force this to a DataFrame using double square brackets:

```
df[['column_of_ints']].apply(function, axis=1)
```

If you're applying row-wise to a single column then you don't need the column accessors in your function:

```
def function(series):
    if series >= 0 and series < 100:
        return series
    elif series >= 100 and series < 200:
        return series + 1   
    else:
        return series + 2
```

but really you should use a vectorised method like my proposal above

Comment: Will this strategy work if I want to overwrite column_of_ints with the same information? Ex: df.loc[(df['column_of_ints'] >= 0) & (df['column_of_ints'] < 100), 'column_of_ints'] df['column_of_ints']

Comment: yes, it will, you can either use 3 `loc` calls to handle each boolean condition to filter the df, or a `where` cal that has a nested `where` to handle the 3 conditions